# NativeScript index in the list of Repeater items

Tags: nativescript, repeater, itemtemplateselector

I am trying to get and use index of the list in NativeScript, in this case using Repeater.

Here is my code:

```
    <ScrollView>                 
        <Repeater items="{{ sviArtikli }}" itemTemplateSelector="$index">
            <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                    <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal"/>                        
            </Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                        <Card:CardView margin="10" width="45%" height="250" item="{{ id }}"  myIndex="{{ $index }}" tap="detaljiArtikla">
                            <grid-layout rows="250, *" columns="*, 50">
                                <Image loaded="slikaUcitana" class="lista-katalozi-slika" id="slicice" opacity="1" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0" src="{{ 'https://url_location/' + slika_image }}" /> 
                            </grid-layout>
                        </Card:CardView>   
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater> 
    </ScrollView>
```

The part with `myIndex="{{ $index }}"` does not work as index can not be calculated in Repeater. 
Is there a way I can get index for every item in repeater? - ListView works, but I can not use listview in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a plyground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=EtkUsj&v=3). You can pass the unique ID in your dataprovider and can access in item.

P.S. There is an open `Feature-request` to support index in repeater, you can also cast your vote there.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing item index is not yet supported in Repeater, but if it's crucial for you, you could extend the Repeater class to support index.

**indexed-repeater.ts** (tested against tns-core-modules v6.0.1)

```
import { Repeater } from "tns-core-modules/ui/repeater";
import { CSSType } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base";
import { parse } from "tns-core-modules/ui/builder";

export module knownTemplates {
    export const itemTemplate = "itemTemplate";
}

@CSSType("Repeater")
export class IndexedRepeater extends Repeater {

    public refresh() {
        if (this.itemsLayout) {
            this.itemsLayout.removeChildren();
        }

        if (!this.items) {
            return;
        }

        const length = this.items.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            const viewToAdd = this.itemTemplate ? parse(this.itemTemplate, this) : (<any>this)._getDefaultItemContent(i);
            const dataItem = (<any>this)._getDataItem(i);
            viewToAdd.bindingContext = {
                item: dataItem,
                index: i
            };
            this.itemsLayout.addChild(viewToAdd);
        }

        (<any>this)._isDirty = false;
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:comps="components/indexed-repeater">
    <comps:IndexedRepeater items="{{ items }}">
        <comps:IndexedRepeater.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ index + ' ' + item.name }}" class="m-10 h3" />
        </comps:IndexedRepeater.itemTemplate>
    </comps:IndexedRepeater>
</ScrollView>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=DSpRW8)

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks and it helped. What I did, without changing any code base is pushing locally generated ID's into JSON element and used them for indexes. 
Now json has { "my_index": "0" ..... } which I change in for loop when fetch is over. I am using those indexes just to scroll the view on certain element in the list.

```
  http.getJSON("https://....")
  .then(function (response){ 
     for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {            
       response[i].my_index = i; // change response on the fly.
       // do something with response....
     } 
    }, function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
  })
```

I guess this could help to someone as well.